# SharedPreferences with get_it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I'm trying to use dependency injection (get_it) and bloc (flutter_bloc) at pet projects. But I faced the problem shown below.

```
I/flutter (23661): Error while creating WeatherInfoLocalDataSource
I/flutter (23661): Error while creating WeatherInfoRepository
I/flutter (23661): Error while creating GetWeatherInfoByCityName
I/flutter (23661): Error while creating WeatherInfoBloc
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
You tried to access an instance of SharedPreferences that is not ready yet
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 404 pos 9: 'instanceFactory.isReady'
```

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\…\pages\weather_info_page.dart:25
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Each child must be laid out exactly once.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
```

I reviewed the articles on github, stackoverflow and reviewed the code from the tutorial, but did not understand what I was doing wrong. Can someone explaint what i'm doing wrong?
Code things:
Injection container

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

void init() {
  //! Features - Weather Check
  // Bloc

  sl.registerFactory(() => WeatherInfoBloc(
        concrete: sl(),
        random: sl(),
        inputConverter: sl(),
      ));

  // UseCases
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetWeatherInfoByCityName(sl()));
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetWeatherByRandomCity(sl()));

  // Repository
  sl.registerLazySingleton<WeatherInfoRepository>(
      () => WeatherInfoRepositoryImpl(
            localDataSource: sl(),
            remoteDataSource: sl(),
            networkInfo: sl(),
          ));

  // Data
  sl.registerLazySingleton<WeatherInfoRemoteDataSource>(
      () => WeatherInfoRemoteDataSourceImpl(httpClient: sl()));

  sl.registerLazySingleton<WeatherInfoLocalDataSource>(
      () => WeatherInfoLocalDataSourceImpl(sharedPreferences: sl()));

  //! Core
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => InputConverter());
  sl.registerLazySingleton<NetworkInfo>(() => NetworkInfoImpl(sl()));

  //! External
  sl.registerSingletonAsync<SharedPreferences>(
      () => SharedPreferences.getInstance());

  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => http.Client);
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => InternetConnectionChecker());
}
```

main

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  di.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue.shade800),
      home: BlocProvider<WeatherInfoBloc>(
        create: (_) => di.sl<WeatherInfoBloc>(),
        child: const WeatherInfoPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Weather info page

```
class WeatherInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherInfoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WeatherInfoPage> createState() => _WeatherInfoPageState();
}

class _WeatherInfoPageState extends State<WeatherInfoPage> {
  //late final WeatherInfoBloc _weatherInfoBloc;

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   //_weatherInfoBloc = sl<WeatherInfoBloc>();
  //   //_weatherInfoBloc.add(const WeatherInfoEvent.loadArticles());
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Weather info'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: _buildBody(context),
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        BlocBuilder<WeatherInfoBloc, WeatherInfoState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is Empty) {
              return const MessageDisplay(
                message: 'Start searching!',
              );
            } else if (state is Loading) {
              return const LoadingWidget();
            } else if (state is Loaded) {
              return WeatherDisplay(weatherInfo: state.weatherInfo);
            } else if (state is Error) {
              return MessageDisplay(
                message: state.message,
              );
            }
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          },
        ),
        // SizedBox(
        //   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
        //   child: const Placeholder(),
        // ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          child: SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        const WeatherControls(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBloc(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<WeatherInfoBloc, WeatherInfoState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is Empty) {
          return const MessageDisplay(
            message: 'Start searching!',
          );
        } else if (state is Loading) {
          return const LoadingWidget();
        } else if (state is Loaded) {
          return WeatherDisplay(weatherInfo: state.weatherInfo);
        } else if (state is Error) {
          return MessageDisplay(
            message: state.message,
          );
        }
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I will supplement the code with other files if necessary.

UPD: Solved by adding await di.sl.allReady(); after await di.init();
and after correcting some omissions.
In the injection, the container forgot to add parentheses to the http.Client and forgot to add an await in the method associated with the bloc.

Answer (score 1):

See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76115955/8888756

```
GetIt.instance.registerLazySingletonAsync<SharedPreferences>(
  () => SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
);
await GetIt.instance.isReady<SharedPreferences>(); // Add this line
GetIt.instance.registerLazySingleton<SharedDataService>(
  () => SharedDataServiceImp(
    GetIt.instance<SecureStorageService>(),
    GetIt.instance<SharedPreferences>(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

its because the consumer of shared preferences is created first before the provider which is shared prefs you need to provide it first before consuming the  dependency so you need to move it somewhere on top so it gets created first before consuming the actual dependency

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help, I moved the part with the shared preference in file injector container, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: can you show me where you moved it? get_it will always create the objects whos at the first line until it reached the bottom whereas other dependencies will be created unlike dagger/hilt in android that it get created wherever you put it

Comment: it's still under //!External comment in injection_container file. Solved this problem by adding await di.sl.allReady(); in main() method.